# Tab layout with activities

Tags: android, android-activity, tabs

I need to create a tab layout with two tabs . Each tab should an activity like Activity1 and Activity2. Activity2 Should Have a button . When I click the button in Activity2, it goes to another new activity Activity3. Now I am in Activity3 and when I press back button of device ,it should come to Activity2 along with tab layout.

How to do this? Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Need to use Activity Group for Retaining Tab Bar in Next Activity.
Check this Post for using Tab Bar using Activity Group :

[Activity Group within Tabhost](http://united-coders.com/nico-heid/use-android-activitygroup-within-tabhost-to-show-different-activity) and [Link for Activity Group](http://gamma-point.com/content/android-how-have-multiple-activities-under-single-tab-tabactivity) and [Sample code for the same](http://ericharlow.blogspot.com/2010_09_01_archive.html)

Comment: I dont want to retain tabbar in Activity3(as per my question) , but when I come  back from Activity3 to Activity2 I need tabbar to be there

Comment: @prabhuM Did you checked the Tutorials?

Comment: @Venkey , Yes I checked the tutorials. I dont want to have Activity3 in tabbar